# How to boost results which are within a certain geospatial distance in Apache Solr, while not excluding other results?

Tags: search, solr, geospatial, spatial-query

So I'm new to solr. In my program, I need to boost the results which fall within a radius of 250 km, however this should be only boosting, not filtering. I still want to see other results, just below these results.

I know that for filtering we use

`fq={!geofilt pt=18.5204303,73.8567437 sfield=latlon d=250}`

However, when I tried to turn it into a boost query using

`bq={!geofilt pt=18.5204303,73.8567437 sfield=latlon d=250}^1.5`

it had no effect.

I also tried:

`&boost=map(dist(2, 18.5204303, 73.8567437, latlon_0_coordinate, latlon_1_coordinate),0,250,2,1)`

which had no effect either.

I tried exploring other options but none seem to work. I know there is an option to boost results in decreasing order of distance but that is not what I want. I want to boost all results within 250 km equally.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try using `geodist()` together with `map`? `dist` doesn't give you an actual distance, just the "abstract" distance between two vectors (so it wouldn't map to 250km).

Comment: I used geodist() and it did help to some extent. My current query is:

```&boost={!func}map(geodist(latlon,18.5204,73.8567),0,250,500,1)```

wherein the documents which are within 0 to 250 km of the given coordinates get boosted by 500.